# e.stopPropagation not working

Tags: javascript, css, events, transition, stoppropagation

I added a `transtionend` callback event to an element. This element has a child that has a transition as well.

The problem is that, when the child's transition ends, its' parent `transitionend` event gets called.

I tried adding `e.stopPropagation()` to the `transitionend` event, but it didn't help. It didn't seem like it did anything. How can I prevent the `transitionend` event happening when the child finishes its transition?

#### JSFiddle

```js
var outer = document.getElementById('outer'),
  content = document.getElementById('content'),
  outerButton = document.getElementById('outerButton'),
  contentButton = document.getElementById('contentButton');

outerButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
  outer.style.width = (outer.style.width === '300px') ? '500px' : '300px';
});

contentButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
  content.style.width = (content.style.width === '150px') ? '250px' : '150px';
});

if ('transition' in document.documentElement.style) {
  outer.addEventListener('transitionend', function(e) {
    alert('transitionend');
    console.log('before');
    e.stopPropagation();
    console.log('after');
  });
}
```

```css
#outer {
  width: 500px;
  background-color: orange;
  transition: width 0.7s ease-in-out;
}
#content {
  background-image: url("http://i.imgur.com/nri7bYd.jpg");
  height: 200px;
  width: 250px;
  transition: width 0.7s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<div id="outer">
  <div id="content">This is some content</div>
</div>

<button id="outerButton">Change Width of Outer (orange) Element</button>
<br />
<br />
<button id="contentButton">Change Width of Content (image) Element</button>
```

Comment: I don't understand the problem; it seems to be working fine on here (chrome 49 and firefox 45);

Comment: @freestock.tk It works fine, but the `transitionend` event executes when `content`'s animation ends. I want the `transitionend` event to only execute when the outer divs' event ends, not content

Comment: so i think you could add an alert on the event to let the question more clear [**example**](http://jsfiddle.net/h42dqksx/1/)

Comment: Good point! I updated question

Comment: try (return false;) -- https://jsfiddle.net/fxbyu2eq/

Comment: @Tasos If I do `return false`, it will also stop execution when outer finishes the transition. All I want is outers children not call `transitionend` event, but the event should get called when outer finishes its transition

Comment: use a flag variable to know which anim was fired and then an if statement for the return  false

Comment: events bubble to parents, so be sure `e.target` is correct before acting.

Comment: @dandavis Do you mean to say like Avinash Agrawal Answered?

Comment: @Jessica: yeah, just like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I have understood from the question and comments is that you don't want transitionend event to happen on child element.

From the code above , since you have applied transition end event to your parent (in this case outer), hence this will capture all the child event as well.

Best way to deal with this problem is to add a check, in the method.

```
if ('transition' in document.documentElement.style) {
  outer.addEventListener('transitionend', function(e) {
if(e.target == content) { return;}
    console.log('before');
    e.stopPropagation();
    console.log('after');
  });
}
```

Here e.stopPropagation(); stops the event to further propagate, for example if you had grandParent div , then the event will not go there, but in this case since the event is coming from child, it is catched by  outer.addEventListener...So best way is to check the event target and then take a decision.

Hope it helps!!

Comment: That explains things! Finally someone that understand what I'm asking! Thanks! Isn't that so inefficient of javascript to make you do that?

Comment: I don't know who downvoted this... but it really isn't efficient, your looping through all the elements which have the prop `transition` checking if true and then checking if the `e.target == content`... which is just sucking up memory. Take a look at my example, it's as efficient as it can get.

Comment: This is the right way. Sort of an event delegation which is in fact more memory efficient. BTW, @JordanDavis you're wrong with your comment since there is no loop involves, it just a check whether that property exists in that object/prototype chain.

Comment: So who is right? Which is the better way of doing it? I'm not siding with anyone, but @dandavis said in the comments above (the comments at the question) to do it like Avinash Agrawal

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand your looking for this:

[Here is the **JSFiddle** demo](https://jsfiddle.net/h42dqksx/4/)

```
init=()=>{
//VARIABLE DECLARATION  
var outer = document.getElementById('outer'),
    content = document.getElementById('content'),
    outerButton = document.getElementById('outerButton'),
    contentButton = document.getElementById('contentButton');
//SET EVENT LISTENERS
outerButton.addEventListener('click',()=>outer.style.width = (outer.style.width === '300px') ? '500px' : '300px');
outer.addEventListener('transitionend',()=>console.log('PARENT (OUTER) CSS TRANSISITION ENDING...'));
content.addEventListener('transitionend',(e)=>e.stopPropagation());
contentButton.addEventListener('click',()=>content.style.width = (content.style.width === '150px') ? '250px' : '150px');
}
//INIT
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', init);
```

Comment: Thanks, but I want the `transitionend` event to get fired by the parent (outer) element. **Not** the child (content)

Comment: @Jessica so you want the event to fire off the parent element's (outer) `transitionend` event, and you want to stop the propogation to the child (content)?

Comment: That's exactly what I want.

Comment: @Jessica gotcha :) so the `e.stopPropagation()` has to be set on the child using the same event listener type... so if you want to block say a `click` event from "bubbling" or "propagating" down to the children you have to add  a listener of same type so ie. click or in this case `transitionend`, I'll update the code